# Transparency in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: transparency, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm aware that hyperledger is suitable for businesses who care about their data confidentiality. But, I'd like to use it for the cases where data transparency matters too.

**Questions**: In hyperledger fabric, can we set our blockchain in a way that public can read it, but only certificate holders can write (or send transaction) to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. I just created a registered guest account. It still uses certs and the chaincode controls access. Set to read only for GUEST. Technically a query is a transaction. You could have the web app just login as guest when the page loads.

[BPN Dev Network Org 1](https://bpn-dev-web.belltane.com)
[BPN Dev Network Org 2](https://bpn-dev-web.byrlin.com)